# How to access environment variable in client side in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I try to deploy a React app on heroku, but any process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE return `undefined` to me, but when I access the app through cli, I can see the environment variable working. Any idea how to make the environment variable work so my client side react code can access it?

Answer (score 1):

Your Heroku environment variables are only directly available to your server-side code. If you need to access them in client-side code, you will need to add logic in your client to retrieve whatever env vars it needs from the server.